# Grails spock unit test, Stubbing a method returns empty list values

Tags: grails, spock

I have spock unit test, and trying to do a service method stubbing to return a list of domain objects, below is what is did in setup fixture:

```
def themeServiceMock = Mock(ThemeService)

themeServiceMock.getTheme(*_) >> {
   return [new Theme(name:'Family', slug:'family'), new Theme(name:'Luxury', slug:'luxury')]
}
```

This service is Mock()ed to another service which is under specification.

On when feature of my test, when a call is made getTheme() of service under spec, it calls themeservice.getTheme(), and returns an list of Theme object with null values. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Note: I also tried to Mock Theme but didn't work either, in that case it was returning null list

Comment: If you found my answer useful please accept and upvote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh man Oh man..... dont know what was wrong but this is how i got it fixed:

I just changed:

```
return [new Theme(name:'Family', slug:'family'), new Theme(name:'Luxury', slug:'luxury')]
```

TO

```
def t1 = new Theme()
t1.name="Family"
t1.slug = "family"
def t2 = new Theme()
t2.name="Luxury"
t2.slug="luxury"
return [t1, t2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
def themeServiceMock = Mock(ThemeService) {
   getTheme(_) >> [new Theme(name:'Family', slug:'family'), new Theme(name:'Luxury', slug:'luxury')]
}
```

Comment: nah didnt worked.. gives me list of theme with null values.. thanks for the reply

Comment: Very strange behavior. Are You sure that the mocked service is assigned to correct variable? Can You provide minimal working example?

Answer (score 0):

When I mock method calls in spock, I normally do it like this:

```
themeServiceMock.getTheme(*_) >> [new Theme(name:'Family', slug:'family'), new Theme(name:'Luxury', slug:'luxury')]
```

Have you tried that?

Comment: nah didnt worked.. gives me list of theme with null values.. and thanks for the reply...